# Making a call to another server from a node server deployed on heroku gives timeout error

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have deployed a express server on Heroku, when i try to make get call to any other server i get this error
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.225.208.117:443
            at Object._errnoException (util.js:992)
            at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014)
            at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186)

Below is the code i am trying

```
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
        axios.get("http://www.example.com")
            .then((data)=>{
                res.send(data.data)
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                res.send(error);
            })  

});
```

Comment: Please provide the related code.

Comment: @ngfelixl added the code

Comment: how do we resolve I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Do you found a solution?

Comment: @knoefel That error was because i was hard coding the port number